# What does it mean that "DWORD can be used to declare a variable that contains the 32-bit offset of another variable"?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm currently learning assembly programming by following Kip Irvine's "assembly language x86 programming" book.

I know that `SDWORD` can be used to assign a 32 bits value to a variable e.g.

```
myVariable SDWORD -2147483648 
; assign the minimum negative number -2147483648 that can be contained within a SDWORD
; to variable named myVariable
```

But in the book, the author also wrote

> The DWORD can be used to declare a variable that contains the 32-bit
>   offset of another variable. Below, pVal contains the offset of val3:
>
> ```
> pVal DWORD val3
> ```

I'm not exactly sure what this sentence means? Could someone please explain it to me? Especially what the author meant by `32 bit offset of another variable`?

Comment: The address of another variable. A pointer. Do you know pointers?

Comment: @Jester ah, i think i have got it. So i guess what the author means is that "DWORD can be used to declare a variable that contain the 32 bit ADDRESS of another variable". So with "pVal DWORD val3", we are not assigning the value contained in "val3" to "pVal", we are actually assigning the address of "val3" to "pVal". I hope my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Technically it's an offset in a segment, but in flat memory environment the base is zero except for special cases.

Comment: @Jester awesome. Thanks again for helping out! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>(Jester has basically already answered this in the comments, but just for completeness, I'll post this as an actual answer.)</sub>

You already know that `DWORD` can be used to declare a 32-bit variable, because that's the size of a double-word on x86. So the only confusing part is what is meant by "offset of another variable".

In this case, that's just another way of saying the *address* of that variable, since in the flat (non-segmented) 32-bit memory model, the segment (aka base) is always 0, which means that the offset is the only part that really contributes to the address.

If you are familiar with pointers from a language like C, then he is just saying that you can use a `DWORD` to store a pointer to another variable. On 32-bit x86, pointers are always 32 bits in length, so you would *always* use a `DWORD` to store a pointer, no matter what type/size of variable it pointed to. You would even use this to store a pointer to (address of) a function.

Note, however, that you had originally tagged the question [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64). In 64-bit long mode, pointers are *not* 32 bits—they are 64 bits. Therefore, you couldn't use `DWORD` to hold the address/pointer/offset of another variable. You'd instead need to use `QWORD`, which is a *quad*-word, 64 bits in length, the same size as a pointer.